# Quando eu carrego meu App classe não é reconhecida

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Diz que BadeView não existe no atual contexto nessa linha do xaml.g.cs

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")] 

private global::Xamarin.Forms.BadgeView bdgDesvioFat;
```

como resolver isso?
Meu BadgeView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid      
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"      
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Operacional"     
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"     
    x:Class="Operacional.BadgeView"     
        HeightRequest="16"     
        WidthRequest="16">

    <local:CircleView x:Name="BadgeCircle" 
                      HeightRequest="16" 
                      WidthRequest="16" 
                      CornerRadius="16" 
                      VerticalOptions="Center" 
                      HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    <Label x:Name="BadgeLabel" 
           TextColor="White" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
           FontSize="10"/>
</Grid>
```

e aqui eu chamo o BadgeView dentro do xaml

```
<BadgeView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    x:Name="bdgDesvioFat"
                    BadgeColor="Blue"/>
```

**EDIT1**

Após alterar a minha page com a sugestão do Diego, passou a dar esse erro

> [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG",
>   "0.0.0.0")]
>           private global::Operacional.ViewModels.BadgeView bdgDesvioFat;

**EDIT2**

Esse é a declaração do xaml da página onde quero mostrar o badge. Tem mais image para mostrar. Para não ficar muito grande o post, coloquei apenas esses já que os demais é tudo parecido.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Operacional.Views.Indicadores"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Operacional.ViewModels"
             xmlns:badge="clr-namespace:Operacional.BadgeView.Shared;assembly=BadgeView.Shared"
             Title="pjavax@gmail.com"             
             Icon="person.png"
             >
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0" Margin="0">

            <local:BadgeView x:Name="bdgDesvioFat"
                        BadgeColor="Blue"/>

            <Grid x:Name="grd" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1" Padding="0" Margin="0" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="imgDesvioFat" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{local:ImageResource Operacional.Images.faturamento caixa-28.png}" Aspect="AspectFill">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnDesvioFaturamentoTapReconizerTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                <!--<Label x:Name="lblFaturamento" Text="" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="White" FontSize="9" FontAttributes="Bold" />-->    

                <!--</Grid>-->
                <Image x:Name="imgTckCancelados" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="{local:ImageResource Operacinal.Images.tickets cancelados-05.png}" Aspect="AspectFill">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTckCanceladosTapGestureReconizerTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
```

o que posso fazer para melhorar isso e rodar

**EDIT3**
erro:

> Type ImageResource not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Operacional

Fiz isso, seguindo a dica do colega Diego

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Operacional.Views.Indicadores"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Operacional"
             Title="pjavax@gmail.com"             
             Icon="person.png"
             >

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0" Margin="0">

            <local:BadgeView x:Name="bdgDesvioFat"
                        BadgeColor="Blue"/>

            <Grid x:Name="grd" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1" Padding="0" Margin="0" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="imgDesvioFat" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="{local:ImageResource Operacional.Images.faturamento caixa-28.png}" Aspect="AspectFill">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnDesvioFaturamentoTapReconizerTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
```

Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Na sua Grid, você colocou indevidamente o namespace `local` e não tenho certeza se o resto do conteúdo está correto... acho que deveria ser `<Image x:Name="imgDesvioFat" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="caixa-28.png" Aspect="AspectFill">` somente. Mas a pergunta está desviando o foco original e não acredito que neste ponto seja útil para a comunidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na classe onde você usa um componente que não é da própria plataforma do `Xamarin.Forms`, você precisa antes importar o namespace no XAML, similarmente ao que você faz no `C#` (`using MeuProjeto.Views.Badge;`).

No XAML você declara o `xmlns`. Nesse caso, em toda página que você for usar o componente `BadgeView` você precisará antes declarar o namespace. Por exemplo, assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Operacional"
             x:Class="App.Views.MyPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Aqui vai o conteúdo da sua página-->
        <local:BadgeView x:Name="bdgDesvioFat"
                        BadgeColor="Blue"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Nesse caso, `local` foi o nome que eu escolhi para referenciar àquele namespace nessa página.

[O guia do Xamarin.Forms para desenvolvedores](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/) é essencial para conhecer os recursos e compreender o comportamento da plataforma, recomendo fortemente que invista um tempo consumindo o conteúdo de lá.

Especificamente sobre esse assunto, lá diz:

> You’ll need additional XML namespace declarations to access other classes. Each additional XML namespace declaration defines a new prefix. To access classes local to the shared application PCL, such as AppConstants, XAML programmers often use the prefix `local`.

Fonte: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml_markup_extensions/

---

*Em uma tradução livre feita por mim:*

> Você certamente precisará de declarações adicionais de namespaces no XML para acessar outras classes. Cada namespace adicional define um novo prefixo. Para usar classes locais da aplicação os desenvolvedores geralmente usam o prefixo `local`

**Edição 1**

O código do XAML postado tem alguma confusão e não parece de acordo com a criação do componente `BadgeView` apresentado na questão. De acodo com o código de criação da `BadgeView`, Você deveria declarar no XAML assim:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Operacional.Views.Indicadores"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Operacional"
             Title="pjavax@gmail.com"             
             Icon="person.png"
             >
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0" Margin="0">
            <local:BadgeView x:Name="bdgDesvioFat"
                        BadgeColor="Blue"/>
<!-- ... Todo o resto do seu código -->
```

Comment: Fiz uma edição para indicar o erro que estou pegando

Comment: @pnet aquilo não é uma mensagem de erro. Esse é o código `C#` gerado a partir do XAML, possivelmente do ponto onde está dando o erro. Preciso saber qual a mensagem do erro. Observe que o namespace que está declarado alí é `Operacional.ViewModels.BadgeView` em vez de `Operacional.BadgeView` como eu sugeri (de acordo com o seu código do componente).

Comment: Fiz outra edição, apenas para mostrar como está meu código. Estou lendo o link sobre xaml que vc postou.

Comment: @pnet, acho que você não havia entendido. Eu incluí na resposta o que deve ser o correto para o caso que você mostrou na pergunta. É só copiar e colar, mas a leitura é válida. Acho que você está deixando passar alguns conceitos. Me avisa se funcionou.

Comment: Diego, tenho uma deficiência em entender o cabeçalho do xaml, razão pela qual estou lendo bastante e tentando entender o link passado. Quando eu coloco `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Estapar.AppOperacional"`, por exemplo, porque não reconheceu os componentes na **ViewModel**.

Comment: Pelo que eu estou entendendo, devo colocar a classe BadgeView dentro da pasta onde tenho o ResourceImage(ViewModel) e declarar no cabeçalho do meu xaml, certo?

Comment: Sobre xaml: https://www.wintellectnow.com/Videos/Watch?videoId=xaml-fundamentals

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73710/discussion-between-diego-rafael-souza-and-pnet).